# wsimport generate a client with cookies

Tags: java, jax-ws, maven-plugin, wsimport

I'm generating a client for a SOAP 1.2 service using `wsimport` from the `jaxws-maven-plugin` in maven with the following execution:

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
            <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>${webservice.url}</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <extension>true</extension>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

The first time the client call the proxy, the load balancer generate a cookie and sends it back. The client should send it back so the load balancer knows where (which server) is dedicated to a specific client (the idea is that the first time the client get a server and the cookie identifies the server, then the load balancer sends the client to the same server for every call)

Now, is there a way to tell to the plugin to enable automatically the cookie handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must set the property `SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY`.

Example for a service called HelloService:

```
Hello port = new HelloService().getHelloPort();
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(
    BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY,true);
```

Setting `SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY` tells JAX-WS to accept cookies from the server and to send them back on all subsequent calls -- just like a browser would. This can be used to maintain a session.

Source: [Rama Pulavarthi - Maintaining Session With JAX-WS](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html).